# Unsolvability of $S_{n}$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Is there a short proof for unsolvability of $S_{n}$ without the standard approach of proving the simplicity of $A_{n}$ ? This is good, however, and one can prove this only with basic group theory, without conjugacy classes ; I was just wondering if there was a shorter proof.

Comment: I believe such a proof appears in *Modern Algebra: an Introduction* by John Durbin, around chapter 37 or so. Unfortunately I do not have a copy handy.

Comment: A group is solvable if and only if $G^n=1$ for $n\geq 0$. Not sure if that helps. Also, I'm fairly certain that a finite group is solvable if every proper subgroup is abelain. Maybe you can use those facts to your advantage

Comment: @BrentJ: What you said is not true - there are finite soluble groups with non-abelian proper subgroups. For example, if $H$ is non-abelian and soluble (so, you could take $H$ to be the dihedral group of order $8$, say, or any non-abelian finite $p$-group) and $A$ is abelian then $H\times A$ is also soluble. Clearly $H\times A$ has a proper, non-abelian subgroup.

Comment: I think you're taking what I said as limiting condition or as a definition of solvable. I don't mean for it to be an if and only if statement. I'm sure their are many other solvable groups. But if a group $G$ is finite in which every proper subgroup is abelian, the $G$ is solvable. That wouldn't even be hard to prove I think

Comment: @BrentJ: Sorry, I got what you said upside down.

Answer (score 13):

This follows from the study of the derived (=commutator) subgroups: $[S_n,S_n]=A_n$, $[A_n,A_n]=A_n$ for all $n\ge5$. This is easier to prove than simplicity of $A_n$.

Comment: Just to add a little explicit detail, $[(13),(12)]=(123)$ and $[(134),(125)]=(123)$.